# Spacing between text inside ticks

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

This code:

<CallPanel title={`Scheduled           |          Total: ${something}          Historic: ${somethingElse}`}>

How would I render the above with the huge spacing between each word? Currently if I manually create space, it gets trimmed back to normal on render.

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 1):

For me, I will use `&nbsp` for a whitespace.

It is available in React JSX as well.